# drop down list appears in front of my calender in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Drop Down list comes in front of all the controls. I have a calander extender for the text box which is right above(top) the drop down. when the calender pop's out it goes under i.e behind the drop down. Any solution friends.

Answer (score 0):

How about posting some code/markup?

Answer (score 0):

It wont like it via the google intellisense but you need to add the following to your DropDownList markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" autocomplete="off" />
```

By default if asp.net finds an attribute that it doesnt recognise then it simply passes it through into the underlying html that is generated.

Note 1: There is some kind of AutoComplete setting for this control but this doesnt do what you need it to do, you need the lowercase version like I have stated above.

Note 2: This is a non-standard attribute. It works in FF and IE but it will cause your validation to fail if you run it through the w3c checker.

Comment: Just quickly looked it up, the type I was vaguely referring to is AutoCompleteType="none" (this wont solve your problem) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx

Comment: when i disable it also it comes in front